# How to consume the Blazor Component in other frameworks like Angular, Vue.js and React

Tags: components, blazor

We have developed the Blazor Web components which renders the svg data. Component has dependency with the .NET core libraries(custom dll's). Is it possible to load/integrate the component in Angular or Vue.js project?

Comment: I doubt this will be possible. Is your angular/vue on top of mvc/razor pages or they separate from .net project?

Comment: My Angular project separate from .NET.

Comment: You can not use blazor component with it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using Blazor components within JS projects works!

Blazor components can be instantiated from JavaScript by calling [`JSComponentConfigurationExtensions.RegisterForJavaScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.jscomponentconfigurationextensions.registerforjavascript), which is available from ASP.NET Core 6.0 on.

Bridging the gap from a Blazor component to an Angular component (with @Input, @Output, events, ...) requires some further steps. See the [JavaScript Component Generation](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/main/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/JSComponentGeneration) project from the ASP.NET samples, or  my [BlazorInAngularDemo github project](https://github.com/Xenoage/BlazorInAngularDemo) including a [working demo](https://xenoage.github.io/BlazorInAngularDemo/#/).